# LoadControl from windows application

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, loadcontrol

Is it possible to LoadControl in windows application?

I have email generation as web, but I want to move it to windows service for monthly newsletter.

Emails now are implemented as UserControls, in this way html person can easily modify look & feel.

Current rendering implementation looks like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4000);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

Page page = new Page();

EmailTemplateBase emailCtrl = (EmailTemplateBase)page.LoadControl(
                "Controls/EmailTempaltes/Template.ascx");
// Exception here

emailCtrl.DataContext = dataContext;
emailCtrl.Parameter = parameter;
emailCtrl.RenderMode = renderMode;
emailCtrl.DataBind();
emailCtrl.RenderControl(htw);

subject = emailCtrl.Subject;

string MessageText = sb.ToString().Replace("\t", "").Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");

return MessageText;
```

Comment: LoadControl of what? Why you need to loadControl in the first place to generate emails? elaborate the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me was to call web service, which was able to generate Html from .ascx.

1. Pass necessary parameters to
   webservice
2. in Webservice, Build
   new Page, than LoadControl
3. Set all parameters
4. Do rendering to
   StringBuilder.

You can see code in question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the `LoadControl` method used in asp.net, you can use `Controls.Add` method of the parent control. Just add a panel to be the parent then:

```
UserControl uc1 = new UserControl //this is your usercontrol

Panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);
```

Comment: Microgen - you missed that part that I need it from Windows. I actually had code which do the same from Page. It works great within asp.net, but not from console application environment

Comment: i thought this is a winforms application. you cannot display GUI controls in a console application!

Comment: This is COnsole Application and I need HTML for those WEB controls.